# Is alpha prime ($\alpha'$) exactness the same as exactness in conformal perturbation theory?

Tags: string-theory, terminology, conformal-field-theory, perturbation-theory, sigma-models

I am very confused by these two different notions of exactness. I will avoid equations because I think my problem is conceptual.

Take the world-sheet CFT and deform it with a marginal operator. In order to assess wether or not the resulting theory is conformally invariant, one must make sure the beta-functions are satisfied.

You obtain the beta function corresponding to the marginal deformation by applying the generalized renomalization group equation to the partition function which you have expanded to a specific order in the strength (coupling) of the marginal operator.

Exactness in conformal pertubration theory means, if I understand correctly, that the beta function stays the same if you were to expand the partition function to higher order in the marginal operator. Let me be more clear. If you expand the partition function to linear order in the marginal deformation and say the resulting beta function is exact in conformal perturbation theory, it means that any corrections to this beta function coming from putting more insertions of the marginal operator in the partition function somehow all vanish.

Then there is the question of the $\alpha '$ expansion. $\alpha'$ corrections to the beta function arise when there are non-trivial loop diagrams in the 2d theory. In the example of a marginal tachyonic deformation of the worldsheet CFT of the bosonic string, this tachyon acts as an extra potential for the 2d fields which may introduce an new interaction vertex in the 2d which can thus give rise to loops.

Then are the two types of expansions the same? or are they related? Thanks in advance, I hope this was more or less clear.

Comment: It seems to me they obviously cannot be the same since inserting more insertions of the tachyon will lead to new interactions terms which might generate new divergences. I suppose at each order in conformal perturbation theory, you have a chain of alpha-prime corrections coming from loops that involve the new interaction terms. They are not the same at all. 
If you are lucky enough that your worldsheet theory is exact in conformal perturbation theory, then you only need to worry about the alpha' loops.